# Pagination - jumping to next row when not chronological numbering

Tags: sql, pagination

I'm trying make a simple pagination for a page which displays photos a user has in their photo album.

A simple "PREV - NEXT".

Here is my code thus far:

```
$query = "SELECT count(id) FROM pins WHERE board_id='$boardDetails->id'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$query_data = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$numrows = $query_data[0];

$rows_per_page = 1;
$lastpage      = ceil($numrows/$rows_per_page);

$pageno = (int)$pageno;
if ($pageno > $lastpage) {
   $pageno = $lastpage;
} // if
if ($pageno < 1) {
   $pageno = $boardDetails->id;
} // if

$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pageno - 1) * $rows_per_page .',' .$rows_per_page;

$query = "SELECT * FROM pins $limit";
$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);


if ($pageno == 1) {
   echo " FIRST PREV ";
} else {
   $prevpage = $pageno-1;

   echo "$lastpage posts in this collection.<br>";
   echo " <a href='/board/pins/$boardDetails->id/$prevpage'>PREV</a> ";
} // if


if ($pageno == $lastpage) {
   echo " NEXT LAST ";
} else {
   $nextpage = $pageno+1;
   echo " <a href='/board/pins/$boardDetails->id/$nextpage'>NEXT</a> ";
} // if
```

This gives me the PREV - NEXT links but the number it provides is wrong.

For example,

a photo page is located at mysite.com/photoablums/500/487/
where `500` is the id of the photoalbum and `487` is the id of the photo.

Because the scripts pools ALL photos id's are not unique to their respective albums, so I can have 1000 photos uploads on the site, all with id's 1-1000, but they are in different albums, so the photo with id `450` might be in a different album than the photo with the id `451`.
This throws up the problem that my script simply links to the previous and next id's of the specific photo it is on.
I edited the code to eliminate this error while I tried to figure out the correct way to do it. Currently the above code displays links to the previous and next ALBUM id.

For example, mysite.com/photoalbums/500/487/

clicking next takes to: mysite.com/photoalbums/500/501/
and previous to: mysite.com/photoalbums/500/499/

Obviously, it isn't guaranteed that a photo exists with id's 501 and 499 within the album whose id is 500. So they are dead links.
In anycase, I'm trying to change the NEXT variable anyway - the `487` id, which pertains to the image id, not the album.

To further complicate me the id's aren't chronological in the albums because of the way id's themselves are assigned (to images, not albums).

So album with the `500` id might contain three photos only.
Their id's won't be 1, 2 and 3.
They could be any three numbers.

Can somebody point me in the direction of what to change about the code so I can skip to the next existing row in the photoalbum table in mysql instead of presuming a -1, +1 pagination.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I found the solution in this thread: mysql get previous and next record id

Comment: Can anybody aid me at all with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Query to find the previouis and next photo ID numbers, and build your pagination links using those instead of blindly setting `$nextpage` and `$prevpage`.

Assuming the current photo is stored in $current_photo_id:

```
$next_photo_query = "SELECT count(id) FROM photos WHERE photo_id > '$current_photo_id' LIMIT 1";
$prev_photo_query = "SELECT count(id) FROM photos WHERE photo_id < '$current_photo_id' LIMIT 1";

// next button
$result = mysql_query($next_photo_query);
$next_btn = " <a href='/board/pins/$boardDetails->id/$result->id'>NEXT</a> ";

// prev button
$result = mysql_query($prev_photo_query);
$prev_btn = " <a href='/board/pins/$boardDetails->id/$result->id'>PREV</a> ";
```